# How can I use Correlation Coefficient to calculate change in variables

Tags: statistics, data-science, correlation, pearson-correlation

I calculated a correlation of two dependent variables (size of plot/house vs cost), the correlation stands at 0.87. I want to use this index to measure the increase or decrease in cost if size is increased or decreased. Is it possible using correlation? How?

Answer (score 3):

Correlation only tells us how much two variables are linearly related based on the data we have, but in it does not provide a method to calculate the value of variable given the value of another.

If the variables are linearly related we can predict the actual values that a variable Y will assume when a variable X has some value using Linear Regression:

The idea is to try and fit the data to a linear function, and use it to predict the values:
**Y = bX + a**

Usually we first discover if two variables are related using a Correlation Coefficient(ex. Pearson Coefficient), then we use a Regression method(ex. Linear) to predict values of a variable of interest given another.

Here is an easy to follow tutorial on Linear Regression in Python with some theory:
https://realpython.com/linear-regression-in-python/#what-is-regression

Here a tutorial on the typical problem of house price prediction:
https://blog.akquinet.de/2017/09/19/predicting-house-prices-on-kaggle-part-i/